# Enviroment Specific Dist Folder in Angular

Tags: angular, angular7

I've built an angular application. But I want to deploy the application in test and production environments respectively. Though I created environment specific api URL in environment.qa.ts and environment.prod.ts in Environments folder and respective configurations in angular.json file.

`angular.json`

```
 "baseHref": "/categoryapp/",
        "outputPath": "dist/categoryapp",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        ........  

"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }
            ],
          "baseHref": "/categoryapp/",
          "outputPath": "dist/categoryapp",
              ...........
          },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
              {
                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                 "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
              }
            ],
            "baseHref": "/categorytestapp/",
            "outputPath": "dist/categorytestapp",
            ..........
            }
          }


"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "categoryapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "categoryapp:build:production"
            },
            "qa": {
              "browserTarget": "categoryapp:build:qa"
            }
          }
        }
    .....
    .....
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "categoryapp:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "categoryapp:serve:production"
        },
        "qa": {
          "devServerTarget": "categoryapp:serve:qa"
        }
      }
    }
```

`packeage.json`

```
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "npm run build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

But when I run

`npm run build --configuration=qa --output-hashing=all --base-href /categorytestapp/`

or

`npm run build --configuration=prod --output-hashing=all --base-href /categoryapp/`

command, I could still see the folder structure like  `dist > categoryapp` where it's base href = `/categoryapp/`

I don't understand why it's not overriding the `qa configuration`.

My expected output should be

```
dist ->  categoryapp (Index.html => base href = /categoryapp/)
         categorytestapp (Index.html => base href = /categorytestapp/)
```

Comment: its creating folder but not overriding `href`?

Comment: Neither of them are happening. Even if I'm running `npm run build --configuration=qa --output-hashing=all --base-href /categorytestapp/` , it's not creating categorytestapp folder inside dist. Instead it's creating categoryapp with href = /categoryapp/

Comment: are you getting error? ok.. its not overriding for `qa`. right?

Comment: Yes, it's not overriding QA